# How to write inline javascript in wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am facing an issue , my inline  javascript code is  not  added in page(Created By wordpress).

code

```
function check()
 {
    alert("in check");
    var mname=document.getElementByID("name").value;
    var memail=document.getElementByID("email").value;

    var mresponse=document.getElementByID("response").value
   alert("name"+mname +"length"    +mname.length+"email"+memail+"length"+memail.length+"response"+mresponse+"length"+mresponse.length);

}

</script>
<table style="border: 0px;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td style="border: 0px;">Name <span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
   <td style="border: 0px;"><input id="name" type="text" name="name" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="border: 0px;">Email-Id <span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
    <td style="border: 0px;"><input id="emailid" type="text" name="emailid" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td style="border: 0px;">Your Response <span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
    <td style="border: 0px;"><textarea id="response" cols="40" maxlength="50"     name="response" rows="4"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <input onclick="check();" type="button" value="click" />
```

Do i need to  install any plugin for allowing   java script.

P.S  i am  not  using  wordpress.com ..i am developing  locally

************Updated*******************

i just try  alert box

```
 var mname=document.getElementById("name");
   alert("in check"+mname);
```

and checked in firebug   got  following error

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
alert("in check"+mname);</p>
```

error pointing  towards  that 'p'. But  i did not write that code. i don`t  know why this is appended in generated code?

Comment: Where have you included this code?

Comment: in html code You sre using `id="emailid"` but in javascript you are using `getElementByID("email")` why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i  tried  inline javascript  plugin  and it works for me. You have to just  add  follwing  tags between your js code

```
 [inline]
   your  js code
 [/inline]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
getElementById instead of getElementByID
```

use ';' after

```
var mresponse=document.getElementById("response").value; //forgot ';'
```

and use

```
var memail=document.getElementById("emailid").value;   //use correct id
```

In my system is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Check this video tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjNVryaNz0E

**Updated**

Add JS like this on your any WP Page or Post It works:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var a = 5;
   alert("hello world. The value of a is: " + a);
 </script>
```

FYI :it does not required any plugin for add js into WordPress page /post

I hope this helps you!!

Comment: i check  my generarted html in firebug...but my  javascript is not added to  page.

Comment: @saurabh which version of WP you are using? and also from where you are adding JS code into your page i.e using dashboard OR from any php template file?

Comment: i am  using wp 3.8 and adding  javascript  from dashboard. but WP appending  </p> before any  java script code..that is why its  not working..i dont  know  why  it is not recognize js.

Comment: Okay, I guess you missing something because I have checked on same wp version 3.8.2 and its working fine, let me know you one thing that appending <p> before/after script tag will note make any problem for run the JS. can you send me the full screenshot of your dashboard where you adding script on your wp page, I need to check in which mode you are adding code to page(View/Text).

Comment: I think you should define your js function i.e check() , into any external Js and include that into the given page. then it will work absolutely fine, because I have checked your code by running on wp page. it giving the same error and its because of wp not support code indentation properly in page and add extra <p> into code.